# CakePHP: Use a plugin helper in a plugin element

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, helper, view-helpers

Is it possible to use a plugin helper in a plugin element in CakePHP 2.x?

My directory looks like this:

```
/app/Plugin/
  MyPlugin/
    Controller/
      MyController.php
    View/
      Elements/
        mywidget.ctp
      Helper/
        FooHelper.php
```

What I want to do is to use the widget mywidget.ctp somewhere in my project. In the widget, there is a requestAction()-call to get data from the controller. This data has to be rendered using some of the methods in FooHelper. Loading it in the controller doesn't help here.

I think, it should be possible to do this by loading FooHelper in my AppController's $helpers array, but I don't want it to be loaded everywhere on the site. Is there some other possiblity? I already found a workaround with ClassRegistry::init(), but this doesn't seem to work with plugins?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to load helpers in the view via `$this->Helpers->load('MyPlugin.Foo');` in 2.0+ then us it normally via `$this->Foo->someMethod();`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, works perfectly! Actually, I already tried this and it didn't work because of a Typo in the class name. Mea culpa, tomatoes on my eyes ;-)